# Upload a picture file into an OCR website

Tags: html, vba, excel, input

I am trying to develop an OCR macro using a [free OCR website](http://www.free-ocr.com/). I inspected the HTML code of the "Upload a file" section as shown:

[image]

**Since the code does not have a `value` option neither does it do a postback call, how do I enter my picture file into the "Upload a file" field via Excel VBA?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a jpg file to OCR site via <input \input> in html form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253517/how-to-upload-a-jpg-file-to-ocr-site-via-input-input-in-html-form)